# How to have immutable key-value map in Substrate?

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

I am writing a `key: value` `StorageMap` in `substrate`. I want to make it immutable such that a key is written if non-existent but if it exists:

i) if the value is the same as stored, alright
ii) invalidate the transaction.

I have written the following `runtime` code :

```
use support::{decl_module, decl_storage, dispatch::Result, StorageMap};
use system::ensure_signed;

pub trait Trait: balances::Trait {}

decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as KittyStorage {
        Value: map u64 => T::AccountId;
    }
}

decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {

        fn set_value(origin, value: u64) -> Result {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            <Value<T>>::insert(value, sender);

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

The [official tutorial](https://substrate.dev/substrate-collectables-workshop/#/1/storage-mapping?id=working-with-a-storagemap) talks about mutating the key in the following manner:

```
/// Mutate the value under a key.
fn mutate<R, F: FnOnce(&mut Self::Query) -> R, S: Storage>(key: &K, f: F, storage: &S) -> R;
```

So, how do I make my `key:value` immutable? Should I write my own `StorageMap`? If yes, where should I place that code?

Note: I am new to both substrate and rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make it immutable such that a key is written if non-existent but if it exists:
>
> i) if the value is the same as stored, alright ii) invalidate the transaction.

You can use the [`exists`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageValue.html#tymethod.exists)/[`contains_key`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageMap.html#tymethod.contains_key) api on the storage item, and you should probably be even more explicit by using an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/).

So taking the code you have written, you would modify it like so:

```rust
use support::{decl_module, decl_storage, dispatch::Result, ensure, StorageMap};
use system::ensure_signed;

pub trait Trait: balances::Trait {}

decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as KittyStorage {
        Value: map u64 => Option<T::AccountId>;
    }
}

decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {

        fn set_value(origin, value: u64) -> Result {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            ensure!(!<Value<T>>::contains_key(value), "key already exists");
            <Value<T>>::insert(value, sender);

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are using an `Option` here, you can also read the value and check if it is `Some(value)` or `None` and then error or continue as a result.

What you cannot do is *truly* make the value immutable in storage such that all code would know not to change the value. You would need to write logic to check ahead of time the value is there so that you don't change it.

Comment: Note that in Substrate v1.0 the api was `exists`, but it recently changed to `contains_key`. If you are following the v1.0 tutorial, you should use `exists`.

Comment: Hey Shawn, I did not completely understand the following line:
`What you cannot do is truly make the value immutable in storage such that all code would know not to change the value. You would need to write logic to check ahead of time the value is there so that you don't change it.`
In the code that you've provided, the `ensure!` call does check that the value isn't existing. Doesn't that ensure that no value is overwritten?

Comment: The `ensure` check is indeed checking if there is already a value in the storage. We wrote the logic so that if there is a value, the extrinsic ends early, and no values are updated. However, if you wrote more functions which could possibly change this value, you will need to also check in those functions too.

Comment: Got it!

Thanks :)